# How to open a file received as a binary content in the HTTP body using RestSharp in it's associated editor

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

As per the requirement, I've to call the REST service which will send back an attachment or a file as a binary content of the file in the HTTP body and the appropriate value of the content-type header and i need to open the contents in it's specific editor.

I'm using RestSharp and below is the code for the same: For eg. if the attachment is .doc-

```
var client = new RestClient(Properties.Settings.Default.RestServicesUrl + Constants.RestTicketServices);
var restRq = new RestRequest(Constants.SearchTicket);
restRq.Method = Method.GET;
restRq.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRq.AddParameter("account_id", "10");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(Properties.Settings.Default.RestAuthenticationUserName, Properties.Settings.Default.RestAuthenticationPass);
IRestResponse rest = client.Execute(restRq);
```

So, after this call:

```
rest.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=utf-8"
rest.Content = has binary data for the word document
```

and so on....

Basically, I'm looking how i can read the binary contents and open the same in the associated editor.

.xls - Excel
.doc - Word
.pdf - Adobe and so on.....

Answer (score 13):

It's one year late, but recently i've searched answer for OP question and found it - just replace last line of your code:

```
byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData(restRq);
```

If You want to have also an IRestResponse, then You can get RawBytes by:

```
IRestResponse rest = client.Execute(restRq);
byte[] bytes = rest.RawBytes;
```

More interesting methods explained in [RestSharp source](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/RestClient.Sync.cs).

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the file (i.e the binary content) to disk first. Then it's simply a matter of opening it:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, response.Content);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

Comment: The signature of File.WriteAllBytes expects a byte[], response.Content is string, thus, this code doesn't compile.